# How to easily convert an unsigned string to a string?

Tags: c++, string, char

I define an unsigned string as a string containing unsigned chars:

```
namespace std
{
   typedef basic_string<unsigned char> ustring;
}
```

Thus, given a basic `std::string` whose chars range from -128 to 127, how can I easily convert it to a `std::ustring` whose chars range from 0 to 255?

Comment: off topic: I question the decision to place this in the `std` namespace. It's not standard. If you have a good reason to do this I recommend documenting the smurf out of why to forestall all of the "Dude! WTF!?!" questions this will result in.

Comment: @Ðаn I store a list of numbers ranging from 0 to 255 in a string and save the string into a file. When I extract it from the file, I get a string but I would like an "ustring" to restore the numbers in the correct range. I could also do `(int)(unsigned char)input[i]` to convert each signed char into a number between 0 and 255 but it seems a bit makeshift, as I'd need to do it several times.

Comment: @user4581301 This is just a little project on my own. Though you are right, I will change it.

Comment: If you have a series of numbers why not use a `vector`?

Comment: I need to have the numbers in a string then (implementing a Move To Front algorithm), so I don't think it would be worth the time converting a vector of chars to a string

Comment: I don't say that one is better than the other for my specific problem but as I said I have a `string` as an input and as an output so I would need to do the conversion between `string` and `vector<char>` twice

Answer (score 2):

You do:

```
using ustring = std::vector<unsigned char>;
std::string a("abc");
ustring b(a.begin(), a.end());
```

Note that the zero-terminator is not copied.

---

`basic_string<unsigned char>` would require specializing [`char_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits). And no new names can be added to namespace `std`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is legal to add specializations to `std`.  You can't add new stuff but you can specialize an existing template.

Comment: @NathanOliver A new name is not a specialization of a template.

Comment: I also just saw you can only add a specialization for user defined types.  If there does not exist one for a built in type then it is UB.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may use the iterator constructor:

```
ustring to_ustring(const std::string& s)
{
    return {s.begin(), s.end()};
}
```

Comment: Or `return ustring(s.begin(), s.end());` prior to C++11.